# BeginForm in Partial View does not fire controller method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dialog

My web app is in MVC and I have a .cshtml page with a `<form>` in it as well as a partial view with @using

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Media", FormMethod.Post, new { @encType = "multipart/form-data", id = "frmImageUpload" })).
```

In JQuery I have `$('#frmImageUpload').submit()` on a button click. However, nothing happens i.e form does not post to controller. I should mention that the submit method is called from button of a dialog.
Is there something fundamentally wrong with my code?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Check your Jquery Library and make sure you have the correct versions....

Answer (score 1):

oops!!! my mistake. just realized I had the partial view inside parent form which makes a nested form. MVC allows multiple form tags on a page with different actions but not nested forms. Once I replaced partial view out of parent form, everything was OK.
Hope this helps others too.